# "Command not found" when I executed my nodejs single executable

Tags: node.js, executable

I've recently built a single executable for my nodejs project by nodejs v20. It works fine when the executable is under my nodejs directory.
However, when I move the executable to another directory, the command line shows "command not found" and I have no idea what's going on.

This script is the reference I used for building an executable.
https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html

I also created a simple nodejs project for testing. The executable cannot run as expected when I moved it to antoher directory. "Commend not found" showed as well.

There are all files in my directory that would like to run the nodejs executable.

> package-lock.json
> package.json
> pulse.yml
> pulsetracker
> sea-config.json
> sea-prep.blob
> .env

Is there any suggestion for building nodejs single executable?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.